# UIL - listview reuse makes images update slowly

Tags: android, android-listview, universal-image-loader

I am using the Universal Image Loader and I have a `ListView` with an image in each row. When scrolling down quickly the images are not updated and the old image is used. However, when scrolling down slowly the images are able of updating, but it takes some time. This makes the impression that the list is repeating itself.
These are my options:

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)

            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(0, true, false, false))
            .build();
```

And this is how I load my image the `getView()`-method:

```
                    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(MY_IMAGE_URL+imageid, holder.imgView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                            holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.placeHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                            String message = null;
                            switch (failReason.getType()) {
                                case IO_ERROR:
                                    message = "Input/Output error";
                                    break;
                                case DECODING_ERROR:
                                    message = "Image can't be decoded";
                                    break;
                                case NETWORK_DENIED:
                                    message = "Downloads are denied";
                                    break;
                                case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                                    message = "Out Of Memory error";
                                    break;
                                case UNKNOWN:
                                    message = "Unknown error";
                                    break;
                            }
                            //Toast.makeText(ImagePagerActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                            holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.placeHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });
```

How can I ensure the images are loaded correctly in the listview?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(MY_IMAGE_URL+imageid, holder.imgView, options);
```

to load images inside adapter..

Update DisplayImageOptions as follows

```
  options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(android.R.color.transparent)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(android.R.color.transparent)
                .showImageOnFail(android.R.color.transparent)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .build();
```

Show and hide the progressbar inside `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` of `AsyncTask` which is called by the fragment/activity which contains the list